# Jorani - Unable to load the requested language file: language/fr/global_lang.php

Tags: php, linux, apache, .htaccess, centos

I'm trying to "install" [Jorani](http://jorani.org/how-to-install-jorani.html) on a `CentOS server`. The doc is written for Ubuntu/Debian or the like, so I've had to search and adapt it. So far so good. I cannot change the distro, I have to use CentOS.

I successfully accessed the index page earlier, but it was in English. I changed it to French and there it is. The error is in the title. If I change the `config.php` file of `Jorani` to  `en` instead of `fr` same error.

The only thing i'm not sure of, is the `mod_rewrite/.htaccess` part of the tutorial. Since it's not Debian, I've had to do it manually, and there's all kinds of contracditing info on the web, I've tried a few and reverted back if it didn't work, but no go. (Things with sites_enabled/available folders, symbolic links, etc.. Very confusing stuff.)

More Info :

- `CentOS 7`
- `Path : /var/www/html/jorani`
- [httpd.conf](http://pastebin.com/R13tFAtZ)

Been on it for a few hours now, any pointers ? Thanks a lot :)

Comment: anyone ? Still haven't found the solution :(.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it.

For people using Jorani, there's a requirements.php so for http://serverIP/requirements.php that'll list everything. What's working and what's not, what you need to enable, etc.

Discover that everything was okay, so I searched elsewhere.

Apparently, the documentation tells you to use "en, fr, de" in the config/config.php files to change the default language, but it doesn't work. I checked the folders and the folder were name "english, french, etc."

Changed "fr" to "french", reloaded, and everything worked.

Gonna email the guy soon, and try to reproduce this problem.

Hope this'll help someone.